# How to handle unique user sessions during login in Parse.com?

Tags: session, parse-platform, authentication, parse-cloud-code

While working on a game, we needed to enforce that each user has at most one active session in one installation.

Ideally if an user tried to login while they had another active session, we should stop the login process and prompt them to what they prefer: continue the login and possibly lose unsaved data from the old session, or abort the login and keep the old session active.

However, in order to view the user's sessions, we need to log them in first. This important for security reasons, and is totally fine since a priori we should be able to do something like this:

1. Log the user in.
2. In an "afterLogin" trigger, check to see if there are any old active sessions from different installations.
3. If there are, abort the login (logging them out) with a particular error code/message.
4. Upon receiving this error code, the app could prompt the user, asking which session they prefer keeping.
5. The user may abort the login, in which case we should do nothing, or they may decide to use this new session, in which case we could send a login request passing an extra parameter to indicate we're forcing a new session.
6. We log the user in again, and since we received this extra parameter, the "beforeLogin" trigger would know to revoke and delete any old sessions.

The problem is that, obviously, there are no "beforeLogin" and "afterLogin" triggers. There's also no way to pass extra parameters to the login request.

We can work around this by calling a cloud function that handles the sessions in the login success callback in the app... but then it's easy to think of scenarios where an user ends up fully logged in with two sessions from two different installations, and we end up having to deal with them.

We also thought of logging them in via a cloud function, but that too seemed to bring more problems rather than solving them.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: This is highly operating system dependent, and has little to do with programming.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the operating system. Parse.com is a web service.